# How to extract parameters of a url via regex in Nginx rewrite module?

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8085/test2/Y2hpc3Rh?sx=MTU5OQ==&sy=MTk4&sz=MTg=
```

and i want to rewrite it to:

```
/tms/$1/$2/$3/$4.png;
```

I have this regex:

```
rewrite /[\w]+/([\w\d]*)?[\w]+[\w]+=([\w\d=]*) /tms/$1/$2.png;
```

it should work like: `/tms/Y2hpc3Rh/MTU5OQ.png` but it doesn't. Nginx can not find the groups. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
rewrite ^/\w+/(\w*)/?$ /tms/$1/$arg_sx/$arg_sy/$arg_sz.png;
```

Nginx doesn't include the query-string in the match for `rewrite`. You can access the parameters by name via `$arg_name`.

`\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, so it includes digits.

Answer (score 0):

untested

```
http://[^/]+/[^/]+/([^?]+)[^=]+=([^=]+)=.* 

/tms/$1/$2.png
```